# make a route in Rails 3 that takes an id or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How do I make a route that accepts an id or not

Here is my route:

```
match '/cancel_greeting/:id', :to => "greetings#cancel", :as => :cancel_greeting
```

I want it to work if there is an id present or not.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes optional if you put the `:id` in paranthesis like this:

```
match '/cancel_greeting(/:id)', :to => "greetings#cancel", :as => :cancel_greeting
```